# Adding newline in a form dynamically

Tags: javascript, forms, newline, addition

Im dealing with the above problem. I have a form and i want dynamically to add new lines with the form (all of them, not only the one included).

What i have done so far is this (but with no success):

```
echo "<script src='/deltio/add.js' language='Javascript' type='text/javascript'></script>";
echo "<form name='test' method='post' action='test.php'>
        <table border='1' align='center'>
            <div id='add'>
            <tr>
                <th align='right'>Proion</th>
                <th align='right'>Partida</th>
                <th align='right'>Stadio Paragwgis</th> 
                <th align='right'>Paratiriseis</th> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='left'><input name='proion_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
                <td align='left'><input name='partida_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
                <td align='left'><input name='stadio_paragwgis_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
                <td align='left'><input name='paratiriseis_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
            </tr>
            </div>
        </table>
        <align='left'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='OK'/>
        <input type='button' value='Prosthiki' onClick='addInput('add');'>
        </form>
";

Javascript(add.js):
    var counter = 1;
    function add(divName) {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<td align='left'><input name='proion_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>";
        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    }
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What you mean by `new lines`? Adding `\r\n` to code will not work, as HTML will ignore it. Also you can't have `<div>` wrapper for `tr`

Comment: Adding the input texts. Dynamic form

Comment: Step 1: Stop creating invalid HTML - you can not have `div` as a child of `table`

Comment: you should append ur div to the existing div , and ur html is invalid wrap up your whole content in divs.

Comment: How do i do that. Im a little bit confused and im kinda junior to this

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you have a button in a form, which is submitting your form by default.

The second problem is You are using div in table, which is not valid, browsers will automatically close the opening tag. If you would like to add tds dinamically, add an empty tr and append new elements to that.

AND the root cause is you're trying to call 'addInput' function, and you have 'add'.

So the solution is similar to this:

```
      <table border='1' align='center'id='add'>
        <tr >
            <th align='right'>Proion</th>
            <th align='right'>Partida</th>
            <th align='right'>Stadio Paragwgis</th> 
            <th align='right'>Paratiriseis</th> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='left'><input name='proion_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
            <td align='left'><input name='partida_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
            <td align='left'><input name='stadio_paragwgis_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
            <td align='left'><input name='paratiriseis_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <align='left'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='OK'/>
    <input type='button' value='Prosthiki' onclick="add('add');">

var counter = 1;
function add(divName) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('tr');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<td align='left'><input name='proion_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

Comment: Its not working. Might have i done something else wrong ?

Comment: No, its just not responding once the button is clicked.

Comment: I created a codepen with my solution: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwBqVZ

Comment: As you're using PHP for writing the content, look after the ' and " characters. I changed `onclick="add('add');"` part. In your code you should escape " chars.

Comment: If the js file is not loading you should see an error in console or in the network tab.

Comment: The js should be in 'deltio' folder, and named 'add.js'.

Comment: Still not working. Im having the same code as Arpad Hollo gave above. My .js file is as follows.

function add(divName) {
 var newdiv = document.createElement('tr');
 newdiv.innerHTML = "<td>....</td>";
 document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}

and the script src as given above in the test.php file

Comment: Without seeing I can't debug your code. Please check again if you missed something, check if you escaped everything well, or paste again your code.

Comment: Replace `onclick='add('add');'` with `onclick=\"add('add');\"`

Comment: any luck @ubuntu_user ?

Comment: Nothing yet. I cannot understand what the problem might be.

Comment: did you try replace the onclick part as I mentioned above? Check the source code in the browser(Ctrl+u) and compare with the desired output.

Comment: I did change the code, but nothing yet. I will try upload the code on my server and see it live.

Comment: Ok, let me see.

Comment: No update. I uploaded the code to the server and it didnt work. I think the problem is in the function, cause if i use for instance, window.print() it will work by pressing the button. Although, i still cant figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: Change the order of echos. First print the form, than the js include.

Answer (score 0):

Am i missing something ?

test.php

```
    <?php   
    echo "<script src='/deltio/add.js' language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'></script>";
    echo "<form name='test' method='post' action='test.php'>
            <table border='1' align='center' id='add'>
                <tr>
                    <th align='right'>Proion</th>
                    <th align='right'>Partida</th>
                    <th align='right'>Stadio Paragwgis</th> 
                    <th align='right'>Paratiriseis</th> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align='left'><input name='proion_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
                    <td align='left'><input name='partida_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
                    <td align='left'><input name='stadio_paragwgis_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
                    <td align='left'><input name='paratiriseis_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <align='left'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='OK'/>
            <input type='button' value='Prosthiki' onclick='add('add');'>
            </form>
    ";
?>
```

add.js

```
    function add(divName) {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('tr');
        newdiv.innerHTML = '<td align='left'><input name='proion_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>';
        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the problem. The code needs this part of code outside of php tag, as follows:

```
 <?php
    echo "<script src='/test/add.js'></script>
        <form name='test' method='post' action='test.php'>
        <table border='1' align='center'id='add'>
        <tr >
            <th align='right'>Proion</th>
            <th align='right'>Partida</th>
            <th align='right'>Stadio Paragwgis</th> 
            <th align='right'>Paratiriseis</th> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='left'><input name='proion_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
            <td align='left'><input name='partida_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
            <td align='left'><input name='stadio_paragwgis_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
            <td align='left'><input name='paratiriseis_paragwgi' type='text'/><br/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <p align='center'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='OK'/>
        <input type='button' value='Prosthiki' onclick=";?>"add('add');"<?php echo "></form></p>
    ";
?>
```

Why is that happening ?

Comment: You don't need to put that part outside of the php tags. You only need to be careful with the escaping, just as I wrote to you in a comment above. That line should be this: `<input type='button' value='Prosthiki' onclick=\"add('add');\" /></form></p>`

Comment: I had it written as you mentioned. I will check it again. However, thank you very much for your help :)